# delete 50 random rows in a txt files that have their second column labeled as 0

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing, sed, awk

I want to use the terminal commands for deleting 50 random rows from a txt file that is tab separated and has these sample rows where the second column is 0. The value in the second column is either 0 or 1. This is a txt file without header. How should I do this?

```
TCGA-05-4244-01 0   TCGA-05-4244-01A-01-TS1
TCGA-05-4249-01 0   TCGA-05-4249-01A-01-TS1
TCGA-05-4250-01 0   TCGA-05-4250-01A-01-TS1
TCGA-05-4382-01 1   TCGA-05-4382-01A-01-TS1
TCGA-05-4384-01 0   TCGA-05-4384-01A-01-TS1
TCGA-05-4389-01 0   TCGA-05-4389-01A-01-TS1
TCGA-05-4390-01 0   TCGA-05-4390-01A-01-TS1
TCGA-05-4395-01 0   TCGA-05-4395-01A-01-TS1
TCGA-05-4397-01 0   TCGA-05-4397-01A-01-TS1
```

Comment: What does "random" mean? Does it mean you don't know where they are OR do you want to use a random number generator to pick them?

Comment: by random I meant sampling. What I meant is not to take all rows where their index is divisible by 3 or the first 50 rows. Not sure what better term I could use.

Comment: @MonaJalal that makes your question even more confusing. You should modify your question to show the output you want for the given sample input.

Comment: @MonaJalal but you only want to sample rows that have `0` on their second column?

Answer (score 3):

Try `awk`:

```bsh
awk '
  NR==FNR {lines[$0]++;next}
  (not FNR in lines)
' <(awk -F '\t' '$2==0{print NR}' file.txt | shuf -n 50) file.txt
```

- `awk -F '\t' '$2==0{print NR}' file.txt | shuf -n 50` will select 50 random lines with `$2==0` to delete.
- `NR==FNR {lines[$0]++;next}` will get these line numbers as array `lines`-(to-delete).
- `(not FNR in lines)` will get the lines that are not in the lines-to-delete variable and do the default action (=`print`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

i=1
nlines=$(wc -l < "$1")

while [[ $i -le 50 ]]; do
    row=$((1 + $RANDOM % nlines))
    num=$(sed -n "${row}p" "$1" | cut -f 2)

    if [[ $num -eq 0 ]]; then
        sed -i "${row}d" "$1"
        ((nlines--))
        ((i++))
    fi
done
```

Save it to a `.sh` file with the name of your choice (I'm using the name `myscript.sh` here) and make it executable by running:

```
chmod u+x myscript.sh
```

Then use it as follows to remove 50 lines containing `0` in the second column randomly of a file named `file.txt`:

```
myscript.sh /path/to/your/file.txt
```

**NOTES**

- Test the script in sample data first to make sure that it works as intended. DO NOT USE IT ON RESEARCH DATA AS THEY WILL BE PERMANENTLY ALTERED!
- The script will save changes to the same file that you use as argument (`file.txt`). MAKE SURE TO KEEP COPIES OF THE ORIGINAL DATA!
- The script does not check for empty lines, so make sure that you have no empty lines in your data.

Comment: Your script renumbers all the lines `${row}+1` to the end, every time. Try it on a 51 line file to see. Does Not Work

Comment: @waltinator thanks for the feedback! I just tested the script for the case you mentioned and it works fine, IF there are 50 `0`'s in column 2. If not, the script goes in an endless loop. This is the core script and I haven't added any tests in order to keep it simple. If the OP needs more than what they script currently does, they may adjust it to their needs, or the can let us know what their needs are, so that I can adjust it accordingly.

Comment: It should be noted that I haven't used `${row}+1` anywhere in the script. There is a random integer number generated though each time the loop runs (`row=$((1 + $RANDOM % nlines))`), which takes into account that the number of lines is reduced if the line specified by that random number contains `0` on the second column, thus the line is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use the `sed` command to delete all lines that contain a tab space, followed by a zero, followed by a tab space.

Use the following command to test the output of the command:

```
sed -e '/\t0\t/d' filename
```

where "filename" is the actual name of the file.

If you are satisfied with the previous output, you can use the following command to actually edit and apply the changes to the file:

```
sed -i '/\t0\t/d' filename
```

again, where "filename" is the actual name of the file.

---

First, the `-e` option is for "expression" but this essentially echos the output and does not edit the file.

`/\t0\t/` searches for all lines that contain a tab space, followed by a zero, followed by a tab space.

`/\t0\t/d` Along with the `d`, this will delete all lines that contain a tab space, followed by a zero, followed by a tab space.

Finally, the `-i` option allows us to edit the file "in place" and apply the changes to the file.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question. The OP wants to delete 50 random lines with `0` in the second column, not all lines with `0` in the second column.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I agree with fuzzy that the question is ambiguous. Unless they clarify and claim otherwise, this satisfies the question as it is interpreted. There are many reasons to believe that "random" indicates the randomness of the lines and not a numerical limit that can't be exceeded. 1) I believe that "to randomly delete 50 lines" is more accurate to your assumption. 2) 50 lines aren't listed in the example but the randomness of the lines is shown in the example. 3) These together indicate the OP was distinguishing from an answer that would delete lines 1-3 and 4-8 based on number.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Although, you may be correct — I think the only way to know is to ask the OP.

Comment: Yes, I can see the ambiguity, although I had to try to see it. Sometimes you see things one way and it's hard to see them otherwise. There's a comment asking for clarification from another user. I guess we'll soon know what's the case! :)

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Yeah, as it is now, both our answers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since the values in field 2 are always either `0` or `1`, you can use `gawk` to print only rows where the second field is `1`. This is functionally equivalent to deleting the rows where the second field is `0`:

```
gawk '$2==1' file.txt
```

If that output looks correct, you can replace the contents of the file with this output by using the `-i inplace` option:

```
gawk -i inplace '$2==1' file.txt
```

**EDIT**

If, on the other hand, the intent is to **randomly delete** 50 of the rows whose 2nd column is zero, something like this would work:

```
for n in $(shuf -en50 $(awk '$2==0{print FNR}' file.txt) | sort -gr); do
    sed -i "${n}"d file.txt
done
```

Or as a one-liner:

`for n in $(shuf -en50 $(awk '$2==0{print FNR}' file.txt)|sort -gr); do sed -i "${n}"d file.txt; done`

Expanding this from the inside out:

`awk '$2==0{print FNR}' file.txt` prints the line numbers of all lines in `file.txt` which have `0` in field 2.

`shuf -en50` randomly shuffles the list of line numbers then prints 50 of them (assuming there are at least 50 lines in the `awk` result).

`sort -gr` reverse-sorts (the `g` means numeric sort instead of the default lexicographical sort) those 50 line numbers with highest numbers first (the same sequence we will delete those lines from the file).

The `for` loop processes this number list, assigning the variable `n` to the list item at each iteration then executing `sed -i "${n}"d file.txt` to delete that line number from `file.txt`.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question. The OP wants to delete 50 random lines with `0` in the second column, not all lines with `0` in the second column.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog OP's question is a tad ambiguous but I understood the "random" part as referring to the presence of zeros in column 2.

Comment: Indeed, the text in the body of the question does seem ambiguous. The title, however, is more clear. ;)

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog To me, the title seems ambiguous in the same way. I.e, are the rows with zero in the 2nd column random, or is the choice of which of these rows to delete random?

Comment: Ok! The OP will clarify it I guess.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I don't even think they want to focus on lines with `0`, they just ask for random lines and state that the second field can be either 0 or 1.

Comment: @terdon sure, I might be wrong. Thanks for the edit! :)

Comment: @terdon in that case, why does she mention "where the second column is 0"?

Comment: Well first of all, @Zanna, I did not notice that! :) I focused on the next bit that says the value may be either 1 or 0. I think you and the Beast are probably right.

Comment: @terdon I'm still not sure which 50 lines OP wants though! :S

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete 50 random lines, get a list of 50 random numbers between 1 and the number of lines in the file, and then delete those lines from the file. For example:

```sh
## store the number of lines in the file in the variable $lines
lines=$(wc -l < file)

## Get 50 random numbers from 1 to $lines and print to the file lineNums
seq 1 $lines | shuf -n 50 > lineNums

## Use awk to print except if the current line number is in lineNums
awk 'NR==FNR{lines[$0]++; next} (FNR in lines){next}1' lineNums file >  newfile
```

Comment: Questioner wanted to delete ONLY among records having `0` in the 2nd field. Your Answer doesn't work.

Comment: @waltinator yeah, that's what some people think but it isn't what I read in the question. It's been discussed quite a bit under other answers. We need the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be unable to state your problem clearly, so this answer will be general.

First, write a regular expression to match the lines that are candidates for deletion. Something like

```
grep -En '^[A-Z]{,4}-[0-9]{,2}-[0-9]{,4}-[0-9]{,2}\t0\t'
```

Use this regular expression with `grep -n` to show the line numbers of matching lines. Pipe (`|`) `grep`'s output through `| cut -d: -f1` . Now you have a list of line numbers of candidates for deletion. Store this in a file.

Pick 50 (or however many) lines from this file, randomly, **without** removing any entries, as other answers have shown. Sort these numerically (`sort -n`) for clarity, and use them to generate 50 `sed` delete commands: `<number>d`. Feed this file to `sed -f` and Bob's your uncle.